# На мобильных устройствах справа появляется белая полоса. Я не могу понять какой блок выпал, прошу помощи

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script|Montserrat:300i,400,700&display=swap&subset=cyrillic-ext" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body class="hgf">
  <header class="header" id="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header_inner">
        <div class="logo" data-scroll="#intro">Logo</div>
        <nav class="nav" id="nav">
          <a class="nab_link" href="#" data-scroll="#acc">Point</a>
          <a class="nab_link" href="#" data-scroll="#work">Point</a>
          <a class="nab_link" href="#">Point</a>
          <a class="nab_link" href="#">Point</a>
          <a class="nab_link" href="#">Point</a>
        </nav>

        <button class="toddle" id="nav_toggle" type="button">
                        <span class="ntoddle">Menu</span>
                     </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="intro img1" id="intro">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="intro_in">
        <h2 class="intro_ts">OTEX XETO</h2>
        <h1 class="intro_t">OTEXTO OTEXTO</h1>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="intro_slider">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="sl_in">
          <div class="slider_it active " id="m0"><span class="sl_num">01</span> <span id="m0" class="text_sl">point</span></div>
          <div class="slider_it" id="m1"><span class="sl_num">02</span> <span class="text_sl">point</span></div>
          <div class="slider_it" id="m2"><span class="sl_num">03</span> <span class="text_sl">point</span></div>
          <div class="slider_it" id="m3"><span class="sl_num">04</span> <span class="text_sl">point</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <section class="sect">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="sect_head">
        <h3 class="sect_subt">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
        <h2 class="sect_title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        <div class="sect_t">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card_i">
          <div class="card_img">
            <img src="assets/images/1.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="card_t">opointo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card_i">
          <div class="card_img">
            <img src="assets/images/intro.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="card_t">opointo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card_i">
          <div class="card_img">
            <img src="assets/images/3.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="card_t">opointo</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>




  <div class="stat">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="s">
        <div class="s_i">
          <div class="s_n">37</div>
          <div class="s_t">only five</div>
        </div>
        <div class="s_i">
          <div class="s_n">100</div>
          <div class="s_t">only five</div>
        </div>
        <div class="s_i">
          <div class="s_n">54</div>
          <div class="s_t">only five</div>
        </div>
        <div class="s_i">
          <div class="s_n">90</div>
          <div class="s_t">only five</div>
        </div>
        <div class="s_i">
          <div class="s_n">178</div>
          <div class="s_t">only five</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <section class="sect" id="acc">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="sect_head">
        <h3 class="sect_subt">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
        <h2 class="sect_title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        <div class="sect_t">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
      </div>


      <div class="wd" id="hg">
        <div class="wd_i">
          <img class="w__d" src="assets/images/4.jpg" width="579" height="380">
        </div>
        <div class="wd_i">

          <div class="acc">
            <div class="acc_i" data-collapse="#wd1">
              <div class="acc_h">
                <img src="assets/images/i1.png" class="acc_ic" width="30px" height="30px">
                <div class="acc_title">Lorem Ipsum</div>
              </div>
              <div class="acc_c" id="wd1">
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="acc_i active" data-collapse="#wd2">
              <div class="acc_h" ">
                                  <img src="assets/images/i1.png " class="acc_ic " width="30px " height="30px ">
                                  <div class="acc_title ">Lorem Ipsum</div> 
                               </div>
                                <div class="acc_c " id="wd2 ">
                                   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                            <div class="acc_i " data-collapse="#wd3 ">
                               <div class="acc_h " >
                                  <img src="assets/images/i1.png " class="acc_ic " width="30px " height="30px ">
                                  <div class="acc_title ">Lorem Ipsum</div> 
                               </div>
                                <div class="acc_c " id="wd3 ">
                                   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>

                      </div>
                  </div>

             </div>
         </section>




          <div class="sect sect--g ">
              <div class="container " >
                 <div class="r2 ">
                   <div class="ri2 ">
                       <img class="rimg2 " src="assets/images/45.jpg " >
                      <div class="tr2 ">
                       Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                       </div>
                       <div class="r_a2 ">Lorem Ipsum</div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>  
         <section class="sect " id="work ">
              <div class="container ">
                  <div class="sect_head ">
                     <h3 class="sect_subt ">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                     <h2 class="sect_title ">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                    <div class="sect_t ">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
                  </div> 

             </div>



             <div class="work " >
                    <div class="work_c ">
                        <div class="work_i ">
                            <img class="w_img " src="assets/images/23.jpg " > 
                            <div class="w_inf ">
                              <div class="w_tit ">Lorem Ipsum</div>
                              <div class="w_text ">Lorem Ipsum</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="work_i ">
                            <img class="w_img " src="assets/images/24.jpg "> 
                            <div class="w_inf ">
                              <div class="w_tit ">Lorem Ipsum</div>
                              <div class="w_text ">Lorem Ipsum</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="work_c ">
                        <div class="work_i ">
                            <img class="w_img " src="assets/images/25.jpg " > 
                            <div class="w_inf ">
                              <div class="w_tit ">Lorem Ipsum</div>
                              <div class="w_text ">Lorem Ipsum</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="work_i ">
                            <img class="w_img " src="assets/images/26.jpeg "> 
                            <div class="w_inf ">
                              <div class="w_tit ">Lorem Ipsum</div>
                              <div class="w_text ">Lorem Ipsum</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="work_c ">
                        <div class="work_i ">
                            <img class="w_img " src="assets/images/22.jpg "> 
                            <div class="w_inf ">
                              <div class="w_tit ">Lorem Ipsum</div>
                              <div class="w_text ">Lorem Ipsum</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="work_c ">
                        <div class="work_i ">
                            <img class="w_img " src="assets/images/27.jpg "> 
                            <div class="w_inf ">
                              <div class="w_tit ">Lorem Ipsum</div>
                              <div class="w_text ">Lorem Ipsum</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="work_i ">
                            <img class="w_img " src="assets/images/28.jpg "> 
                            <div class="w_inf ">
                              <div class="w_tit ">Lorem Ipsum</div>
                              <div class="w_text ">Lorem Ipsum</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
             </div>



        </section>
         <div class="sect ">
              <div class="container ">
                 <div class="r ">
                   <div class="ri ">
                       <img class="rimg " src="assets/images/45.jpg " width="145px " height="145px ">
                      <div class="tr ">
                       Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                       </div>
                       <div class="r_a ">Lorem Ipsum</div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div> 


         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
         <script src="assets/js/app.js ">








         </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*,
*:befor,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15x;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.hgf {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.intro {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 820px;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
}

.intro.img1 {
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("../images/1010.jpg")center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: anim 0.7s;
}

.intro.img2 {
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("../images/1110.jpg") center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: anim 0.7s;
}

.intro.img3 {
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("../images/1210.jpg") center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.intro.img4 {
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("../images/1310.jpg") center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.header.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background: #ad6b5a;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.header.active {
  background: #ad6b5a;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
}

.logo:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nab_link {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.1s linear;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.nab_link:hover {
  color: #fce38a;
}

.nab_link:hover:after,
.nab_link.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.nab_link.active {
  color: #fce38a;
}

button {
  background-color: Transparent;
  border: 0;
}

.toddle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 30px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 0;
  color: transparent;
  background-color: Transparent;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

.toddle:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.toddle.active .ntoddle {
  background: none;
}

.toddle.active .ntoddle:before {
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate3d(0px, -2px, 0);
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}

.toddle.active .ntoddle:after {
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: rotate(-45deg)translate3d(0px, 3px, 0);
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}

.ntoddle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  transition: background 0.2s linear;
}

.ntoddle:before,
.ntoddle:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.ntoddle:before {
  top: -8px;
}

.ntoddle:after {
  bottom: -8px;
}

.header_inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.intro_t {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 150px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
}


}
.intro_in {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 880px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.intro_ts {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
  font-size: 72px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.intro_slider {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.slider_it {
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.1;
  width: 23%;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-top: 3px solid #fff;
}
.sl_num {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.slider_it.active {
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  opacity: 1;
}
.slider_it.active:before {
  content: "";
  width: 70px;
  height: 3px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #ff9b80;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}
.sl_in {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.sect {
  padding: 50px 0;
}
.sect.al {
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
}
.sect--cl {
  background-color: #ffebe6;
}
.sect_head {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 950px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
}
.sect_subt {
  font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #333;
}
.sect_title {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #333;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.sect_title:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #ff9b80;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
.sect_t {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #999;
}
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 80px -15px 0;
}
.card_i {
  position: relative;
  width: 33.33333%;
  max-width: 380px;
  background-color: #ff9b80;
  /**/
  
  margin: 0 15px;
}
.card_img {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F38181, #fce38a);
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}
.card_i:hover .card_img img {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.card_i:hover .card_img {
  /**/
  
  transform: translate3d(-10px, -10px, 0)
}
.card_img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: opacity 0.1s linear;
  display: block;
}
.card_t {
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  transition: opacity 0.1s linear;
}
.card_i:hover .card_t {
  opacity: 1;
}
.stat {
  background-color: #ff9b80;
}
.sect--g {
  background-color: #FFFAFA;
}
.s {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.s_i {
  padding: 70px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #ffad99;
}
.s_i:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #ffad99;
}
.s_n {
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.s_t {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.wd {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 15px;
}
.wd_i {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.w__d {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.acc_i {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ffebe6;
}
.acc_i.active .acc_c {
  display: block;
}
.acc_h {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 65px;
  position: relative;
}
.acc_i.active .acc_h {
  border-bottom-color: #ffebe6;
}
.acc_i.active .acc_h:after {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
  margin-top:
}
.acc_h:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffebe6;
  border-right: 2px solid #ffebe6;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(135deg);
  right: 20px;
  30px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.acc_ic {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.acc_c {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #999;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  display: none;
}
.acc_title {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.wd2 {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 15px;
}
.wd_i2 {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  padding-right: 50%;
}
.w__d2 {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
.acc_i2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
.acc_h2 {
  padding: 10px 5px 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.acc_i2.active .acc_h2 {
  border-bottom-color: #ffebe6;
}
.acc_c2 {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #999;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.acc_title2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.r {
  padding: 0 145px;
}
.ri {
  padding-left: 205px;
  position: relative;
}
.rimg {
  /*    border: 5px solid #ffad99;*/
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 145px;
  height: 145px;
  border: 2px solid #F38181;
  display: block;
}
.tr {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #999;
}
.r_a {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
}
.r_a:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 60px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #ffad99;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.r2 {
  padding: 0 145px;
}
.ri2 {
  padding-left: 205px;
  position: relative;
}
.rimg2 {
  /*    border: 5px solid #ffad99;*/
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 145px;
  height: 145px;
  border: 2px solid #F38181;
  display: block;
}
.tr2 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #999;
}
.r_a2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
}
.r_a2:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 60px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #ffad99;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.work {
  display: flex;
}
.work_c {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}
.work_i {
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F38181, #fce38a);
}
.work_i:hover .w_img {
  opacity: 0.1;
}
.work_i:hover .w_inf {
  opacity: 1;
}
.w_img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
}
.w_inf {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 15px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
}
.w_tit {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.w_text {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
}
.cl {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.cl_i {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
.c_img {
  top: 0;
  left: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
@media (max-width:1230px) {
  .hgf {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  
  .intro_ts {
    font-size: 52px;
  }
  
  .intro_t {
    font-size: 120px;
  }
  
  .card {
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  
  .card_i {
    max-width: 380px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  
  .card_i:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  
  .tr {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
@media (max-width:990px) {
  .hgf {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  
  .intro_ts {
    font-size: 32px;
  }
  
  .intro_t {
    font-size: 80px;
  }
  
  .card {
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  
  .card_i {
    max-width: 380px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  
  .card_i:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  
  .s {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .s_i {
    flex: none;
    width: 33.33333%;
    border: 0;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
  
  .s_i:last-child {
    border: 0;
  }
  
  .wd {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  .w__d {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .wd_i {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .r {
    padding: 0 60px;
  }
  
  .tr {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  
  .ri {
    padding-left: 175px;
  }
  
  .r2 {
    padding: 0 60px;
  }
  
  .tr2 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  
  .ri2 {
    padding-left: 175px;
  }
}
@media (max-width:770px) {
  .hgf {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  
  .intro {
    min-height: 650px;
  }
  
  .header {
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
  
  .nav {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: #ad6b5a;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .nav.active {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .nab_link {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 20px;
  }
  
  .toddle {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .text_sl {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .slider_it.active:before {
    width: 50%;
  }
  
  .sect {
    padding: 40px 0;
  }
  
  .card {
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  
  .card_i {
    max-width: 380px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  
  .card_i:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  
  .tr {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  
  .rimg {
    position: static;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: -25px;
  }
  
  .ri {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  
  .tr2 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  
  .rimg2 {
    position: static;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: -25px;
  }
  
  .ri2 {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  
  .work {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  .work_c {
    flex: none;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
@media (max-width:575px) {
  .hgf {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  
  .intro_ts {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  
  .intro_t {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  
  .sect_head {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  
  .sect_title {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  
  .sect_subt {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  
  .sect_title:after {
    margin: 20px auto;
  }
  
  .s_i {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffad99;
  }
  
  .s_i:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  
  .s_n {
    font-size: 52px;
  }
  
  .tr {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  
  .ri {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  
  .r {
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .tr2 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  
  .ri2 {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  
  .r2 {
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .work_c {
    flex: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .w_img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  var header = $("#header");
  var scrollOffSet = $(window).scrollTop();
  var introH = $("#intro").innerHeight();
  c(scrollOffSet);
  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    scrollOffSet = $(this).scrollTop();
    c(scrollOffSet);


  });

  function c(scrollOffSet) {



    if (scrollOffSet >= introH) {
      header.addClass("fixed");
    } else {
      header.removeClass("fixed");
    }
  }


  $("[data-scroll]").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var Sthis = $(this);
    var blockId = Sthis.data('scroll');
    var blockOffSet = $(blockId).offset().top;
    $("#nav a").removeClass("active");
    Sthis.addClass("active");




    $("#nav").removeClass("active");
    $("#header").removeClass("active");

    /* if(header.hasClass("acrive")){
    $("#nav").toggleClass("active");
    $("#header").toggleClass("active");
    }*/

    $("html,body").animate({
      scrollTop: blockOffSet
    }, 'slow');

  });


});


$("#nav_toggle").on("click", function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $("#nav").toggleClass("active");
  $("#header").toggleClass("active");


});

$("[data-collapse]").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var Sthis = $(this);
  var blockId = Sthis.data('collapse');
  // $("[data-collapse]").removeClass("active");
  Sthis.toggleClass("active");

  $("#nav").toggleClass("active");



});















// установим еще один обработчик события mouseleave, на этот раз элементам 
// с классом block. В обработчик передадим дополнительные данные
var $set = $('.sl_in .slider_it');
$('.slider_it').on("mouseenter ", function() {
  $('.slider_it').removeClass("active");

  $(this).addClass("active");
  var n = $set.index(this);
  /*console.log(n);*/
  /*
   if(n==0){
      $( '.intro' ).removeClass( 'img2').removeClass( 'img3').removeClass( 'img4' );
     $( '.intro' ).addClass( 'img1',3000);
    
   }if  (n == 1){
     $( '.intro' ).removeClass( 'img1').removeClass( 'img3').removeClass( 'img4'); 
    $( '.intro' ).addClass( 'img2',3000); 
    
   }if  (n == 2){
    $( '.intro' ).removeClass( 'img2').removeClass( 'img1').removeClass( 'img4');
     $( '.intro' ).addClass( 'img3',3000);
   }if  (n == 3){
    $( '.intro' ).removeClass( 'img2').removeClass( 'img3').removeClass( 'img1');
     $( '.intro' ).addClass( 'img4',3000);
   }
   
   
 */

});
```